# Schedule a Task periodically in a hosted server c#

Tags: c#

I have a requirement communicating with ftp server after a certain time interval and host it in a cloud. To run a schedule task in a hosted server what should I do? It would be great if someone could point me to a useful online resource.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: You can use `Timer`, can't you?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure about, Whether I should create a web service which run periodically? After hosting the service in cloud will it run automatically without any user interaction.

Comment: In your cloud machine, there is no Task Scheduler or supporting cron job commands?

Comment: I'm haven't even decided on which cloud machine to use. Just trying to get clarification on **How to do** and **Best practice** to acheive it

Answer (score 1):

Most of cloud environments have some kind of scheduler. For example [Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/). 
Also list of pretty good scheduling libraries could be found in Scott Hanselmans article [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I used **Quartz** and it is awesome and straight-forwarded.

A simple example of usage is something like :

```
    using Quartz;

    private ScheduleCopyTask()
    {
        Quartz.IScheduler sched;
        IJobDetail job;
        ITrigger trigger;

        // Instantiate the Quartz.NET scheduler
        var schedulerFactory = new Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
        sched = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        // Instantiate the JobDetail object passing in the type of your
        // custom job class. Your class merely needs to implement a simple
        // interface with a single method called "Execute".
        job = JobBuilder.Create<SyncJob>()
                     .WithIdentity("SyncJob", "group1").Build();


        // Trigger the job to run now, and then every 30 mins
        trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
         .WithIdentity("SyncTrigger", "group1")
         .StartNow()
         .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
         .WithIntervalInMinutes(30)
         .RepeatForever()).Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

And your job class :

```
    class SyncJob : IJob
    {      
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
           // your task goes here
        }
    }
```

You can find Quartz documentation here : http://quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/

Answer (score 0):

I use http://hangfire.io/ for this, it is powerful and yet very simple to use.

You could also use http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/, but I haven't use it so I can't comment on it.