# Read Message from Queue After Certain Time

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Hi i am developing a RabbitMQ library using c# . I have a queue called exceptions queue which has errors data . I want my service to check Exceptions queue after certain time example 5 minutes if there is message in queue read it send ack to it . Any   suggestion how can i schedule or check if there is message in queue read it . 
Many thanks

Comment: Is your question how to schedule in C#? If so, there are many duplicates on SO, but search for Quartz.NET and Hangfire to get you started. If that is not your question - please clarify your question :)

Comment: no i want to check after certain time if there is message in queue if yes read it not redo after time

Comment: "Check after certain time" That is scheduling isn't it? I'm really, really unclear what you are asking for...

Comment: yes correct sorry for confusion i want to use scheduling to check queue if there is message read it hope its clear

Comment: That is clear - in which case, use a good scheduling library like [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) (simple) or [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) (complicated).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schedule a Task periodically in a hosted server c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337583/schedule-a-task-periodically-in-a-hosted-server-c-sharp)